# CentOS 8 not seeing latest Maven package on repository

Tags: centos, yum, maven

I'm using centos 8.3.2011 and after "yum install maven" I get

```
maven-3.5.4-5.module_el8.0.0+39+6a9b6e22.noarch
```

I'm trying to update on the latest version, but "yum update" is not seeing it :-(

"yum -v repolist" shows repositories that have it.

```
http://mirror.centos.plus.hr/centos/8.3.2011/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/

maven-3.5.4-5.module_el8.0.0+39+6a9b6e22.noarch <-- installed
maven-3.6.2-5.module_el8.3.0+397+dd71f484.noarch <-- I would like this version
```

"yum clean all" is not helping :-(

What I'm I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the existing version and installing the specific version of the package that you want, i.e. `yum install maven-3.6.2-5.module_el8.3.0`

Comment: @fpmurphy yes, but it's not possible. I found a solution, I'll post it now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the right way.

Before installing maven, I should switch the version to 3.6 using this:

dnf -y module enable maven:3.6